# Google chart with data from database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problem with drawing google chart with data from database. So basicly I copy/paste code for chart from google. With static data which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');

        data.addRows([

          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2],

        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Ukupna zarada: @ViewBag.Zarada KM',
            pieHole: 0.4,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

This works greate, now I want to populate chart with my data, so I dont want hard coded ['Onions',1] etc. I sent from my data from controller using 2 ViewBag, one ViewBag with string data, and another with number. I tryed to get at least string data from databese using this code. But then i get on screen "No data"

```
 data.addRows([
            @{
                 foreach (var item in ViewBag.LTU)
                 {
                     Html.Raw("['"+item+"', 1],");
                 } 
                }                  
        ]);
```

Is it even possible?
I tryed event this, with hardcoded string, but again i get no data.

```
 data.addRows([
                @{
                     foreach (var item in ViewBag.LTU)
                     {
                         Html.Raw("['something', 1],");
                     } 
                    }                  
            ]);
```

Comment: Passing data from viewbag into a JavaScript ain't going to fly, instead populate a html control and read the vales from JavaScript, the better way is the JavaScript reading from a webservice

Comment: I don't know much about passing data from a viewbag to javascript but I'm pretty sure that if data did contain something like ['something',1] your code should've worked. So the obvious blocking point is that you are failing to fetch your data. Again, I'm with @JeremyThompson on this, the better way is javascript reading from a webservice, ideally data in JSON format.

Comment: Guys, thx for your help, ill try to figure out something.

Comment: @BruceHasetLee:which type of your viewbag . it is array or list ?

Comment: @Amit Kumar: It's List

Comment: @BruceHasetLee: See the answer. If you can post your list then I'll change my answer. As I have assumed It is array .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx everyone for help, but my friend solved this, following code works:

```
 var d1 = [
        @{

            for (var i = 0; i < @LTU.Count; i++)
            { 
                 @Html.Raw("['"+LTU[i]+"', "+Cijene[i]+"] ,")
            }

        }
        ];

        for(var i=0;i<@LTU.Count;i++)
        {
            data.addRows([
                d1[i]
            ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have `array` in your `viewbag` for string and number data.

Now you need to convert those `C#` array into `Js` array.

So I have used `Json.Encode` to convert.

```
var stringData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.mystringDataArray));
var numberData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.mynumberDataArray));
```

Now you can run each loop to fill data row.

```
$.each(stringData, function(startIndex, stringVal){
            data.addRow([stringVal , numberData[startIndex]]);
        });
```